# Jquery update of a div after select or click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have two arrays like this:

```
var people = [
    {value:"name1",data:"1",price1:"15",price2:"20"},// prices are in USD by default
    {value:"name2",data:"2",price1:"12",price2:"17"},...
    ]
var rates = [
    {currency:"EUR",rate:"0.732564"},
    {currency:"GBP",rate:"1.2455"},
    {currency:"USD",rate:"1"},...
    ]
```

i have two dropdown lists with people(value) and rates(currency) like this example:

```
<select name="currencies" onChange=";" value="GO">
    <option selected="selected">Currency</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
    <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
    <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
</select>
```

i have radio buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="button1" name="button" value="5">
<input type="radio" id="button2" name="button" value="10">
```

When i change one of those select or radio button, i would like to make a little math calculation to update the div below, but i don't know how to do it.

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If would be much simpler if you had an object instead of an array : `{'USD':1, 'EUR':0.7....}`

Comment: we can assume we have that, how to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you change the array like i said in comment :

```
var rates = {
    EUR:0.732564,
    GBP:1.2455,
    USD:1,...
}
```

You could use this code :

```
$('select, input').on('change', function(){
    var currency = $('[name="currencies"]').val();
    if(currency && $('input:checked').length){
         $('#result').html(rates[currency] * parseFloat($('input:checked').val()))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select[name="currencies"], input[type="radio"][name="button"]').on('change', function()
{
    // your math calculation to update the div
    $('#result').html('Selected currency: ' + $('select[name="currencies"] option:selected').text() + ' / Price or "button": ' + $('input[type="radio"][name="button"]:checked').val());
});
```

**The code should work, but not tested ^^**

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        updateResult();
    });
});
function updateResult(){
    var currency=$('#currencylist')[0].value;
    var rate=0;
    for(var i=0,il=rates.length;i<il;i++){
        if(rates[i]['currency']==currency){
            rate=Number(rates[i]['rate']);
            break;
        }
    }
    var amount=0;
    var buttons=        document.getElementsByName('button');
    for(var i=0,il=buttons.length;i<il;i++){
        if(buttons[i].checked){
            amount=Number(buttons[i].value);
            break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=        amount*rate;
}
```

and also modify

```
<select name="currencies" onchange="updateResult()" id='currencylist' value="GO">
```